# Print Javascript Response

Tags: javascript, php

I have a php script that responds to a file being uploaded. I want to 'echo' this response but I can't get it to work

As you can see in the script below I used ' response ' because I couldn't think of anything. How does this work?

```
success:function(response){
    if(response == 6563){
        var uploaddiv = document.getElementById('uploadattachment');
        uploaddiv.innerHTML = '<center><br><br><span style="font-size:18px; color:green;">File has successfully been uploaded.</span><br>You can now click this window away or upload another file</center>';
    } else {
        var uploaddiv = document.getElementById('uploadattachment');
        uploaddiv.innerHTML = '<center><br><br><span style="font-size:18px; color:red;">Oops, something went wrong</span><br>' response '</center>';
    }
```

Comment: As a side note, the <center> html tag is outdated. Do the centering with css instead: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to correctly concatenate the string (missing '+'):

```
uploaddiv.innerHTML = '<center><br><br><span style="font-size:18px; color:red;">Oops, something went wrong</span><br>'+response+'</center>';
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Actually did know it had something to do with plusses but din't know it was that similar to PHP :), thanks mate

Answer (score 1):

If you want to inspect the response without adding it to the DOM, use `console.log(response);`
and it will be logged to the developed console of your browser.

Answer (score 1):

May be you mean how to get response code status, code sample:

```
   success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
       console.log(xhr.status);
       alert(xhr.status);
   },
```

So you can handle the response code and process your data according to the status code.

Answer (score 1):

This is the error: You missed a `+` after and before the `response`.

```
var uploaddiv = document.getElementById('uploadattachment');
uploaddiv.innerHTML = '<center><br><br><span style="font-size:18px; color:red;">Oops, something went wrong</span><br>' + response + '</center>';
```